# Creating column with difference in two rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a hash in one column and dates in another column. I want to create a new column with age, i.e., difference between the first date with a particular hash and the current date. As an example, the dataframe `inf` contains

```
inf.head(5)
                                   id       date
0  00047331-29e7-4165-833f-3efcfc2ea90f 2015-08-19
1  0005b350-31ac-443c-8244-21a34120c83d 2015-08-20
2  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-10
3  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-07
4  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-04
```

I add a column called age to this by

```
inf['age'] = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(inf)), index=inf.index)
```

Now I want to convert this to

```
                               id       date  age
0  00047331-29e7-4165-833f-3efcfc2ea90f 2015-08-19    0
1  0005b350-31ac-443c-8244-21a34120c83d 2015-08-20    0
2  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-10    0
3  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-07    -3
4  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-04    -6
```

Where the last column is the difference between a particular id's first date and the date in that row. I am currently using this to perform this:

```
datedict={}
for count in range(len(inf)):
    try:
        inf['age'][count]=inf['date'][count]-datedict[inf['id'][count]]
    except KeyError:
        datedict[inf['udid'][count]]=inf['date'][count]
```

This is working but is disgustingly slow. Took over an hour for 100,000 records. Is there a better way to perform this?

Comment: by current date are you saying today date like `datetime.now()`

Comment: I meant the date in that particular row. Have edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` method for your hashes, then `transform` method for `date` column and `iloc` to get the first element. You also will need to convert your date column to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
In [402]: df
Out[402]: 
                                     id       date
0  00047331-29e7-4165-833f-3efcfc2ea90f 2015-08-19
1  0005b350-31ac-443c-8244-21a34120c83d 2015-08-20
2  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-10
3  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-07
4  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-04

dates = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x:  (x - x.iloc[0])) 

In [405]: dates
Out[405]: 
0   1970-01-01
1   1970-01-01
2   1970-01-01
3   1969-12-29
4   1969-12-26
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I'm not sure why it printing from the begining for 1970-01-01 but you could fix that with substracting from that `pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')`

```
In [408]: dates - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')
Out[408]: 
0    0 days
1    0 days
2    0 days
3   -3 days
4   -6 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you need only values you could use `dt.days` and then pass it to your new column `age`:

```
df['age'] = (dates - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).dt.days

In [415]: df
Out[415]: 
                                     id       date  age
0  00047331-29e7-4165-833f-3efcfc2ea90f 2015-08-19    0
1  0005b350-31ac-443c-8244-21a34120c83d 2015-08-20    0
2  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-10    0
3  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-07   -3
4  0007da63-6fa6-4c0d-a1b1-b09fb0353853 2015-08-04   -6
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Anton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4542359/anton-protopopov), slightly different flavor:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def Age(df):
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df['age'] = [x-df.date[0] for x in df.date]
    return df

df = df.groupby('id').apply(Age)
```